# aws s3 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Stream')

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

When trying to download a file from s3, through   s3.getObject(params),createReadStream() method,

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: 'xx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xx',
    region: 'x',x
    httpOptions: { timeout: 200000 }
  });
  var params = {
    Bucket: "xx",
    Key: 'xx'
  }
  var s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()
    .on('error', function (err) {          
      console.log('READSTREAM error');
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', function () { });
```

it gives me the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Stream')

use "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.54.1",
"aws-sdk": "^2.1095.0",

any idea what can happen?

Comment: My guess is `s3.getObject(params)` returns `undefined`

Comment: I just checked that it returns an object :(

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am getting the same error

Comment: I finally had to do another implementation to download the files, using getSignedUrl method